# Importing Drupal Commerce Orders, Customers, Ship to and Bill to addresses

Tags: commerce

Has anyone successfully imported customers, orders, ship to, and bill to addresses using anything other than a custom module?  If there a recipe for the process?

Answer (score 2):

There's also Migrate Module ; but your question is vague regarding the source you are migrating from.  This module supports different sources to migrate from

https://drupal.org/node/1006986

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, but I would go with Migrate module. You've got a [commerce migrate](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate) module and if you're coming from Ubercart, you have [commerce migrate ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate_ubercart) already baked in - also useful if you want to look for examples. You're going to need to build your own migrate classes, check the [getting started with migrate](https://drupal.org/node/1006982) guide in drupal.org.

Another alternative is using [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module, it will be probably simpler but less robust/customizable, you've got a [commerce feeds](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) module but the [order support is not quite there](https://drupal.org/node/1156952).